# Create a custom widget with PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to create a custom widget with **PyGObject**. For example I want to create this `CustomButton` widget which adds an image and a label in a button (it's just for the example) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*

from gi.repository import Gtk

class ImageButton(Gtk.Widget):

    def __init__(self, label, image):
        Gtk.Widget.__init__(self)

        self.hbox = Gtk.HBox()
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
        self.image = Gtk.Image.new_from_stock(image, Gtk.IconSize.MENU)

        self.hbox.pack_start(self.image, False, False, 3)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.label, False, False, 3)

        self.button = Gtk.Button()
        self.button.add(self.hbox)
```

In another file or class, I can use it like that :

```
button = ImageButton("My label", Gtk.STOCK_HOME)
```

But when I want to use it, I am obliged to call the `button` attribute, like this :

```
# Connect the "clicked" event 
button.button.connect("clicked", on_clicked_button)

# Add the button in a container
window.add(button.button)
```

It works but it is not practical. How to create a custom widget working like any other widget please :

```
button = ImageButton("My label", Gtk.STOCK_HOME)
button.connect("clicked", on_clicked_button)
window.add(button)
```

Comment: Why can't you just write `button.button`?

Comment: It's possible but I want to create a real custom widget. I don't want to write `button.button.connect("clicked", on_clicked_button)`, but just `button.connect("clicked", on_clicked_button)`

Comment: So write a `connect` method...

Comment: I don't really understand why you have a button attribute *and* inherit from `Button`, though.

Comment: I have a button attribute and inherit from `Button` because I thought it was a good solution, but if you have the answer I take it :)

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand what you're trying to do so I wouldn't say I have the solution.

Comment: Ok no problem, I try to rewrite my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55561/discussion-between-ncrocfer-and-veedrac).

Comment: You can have a gtk.EventBox and pack the hbox into it. and connect button_press_event to the eventbox. That would solve i hope!

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem it is actually a problem about understanding classes more then inheritance. If you want your widget to act exactly as a button, it should be a button.

Take a look to the following example:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ImageButton(Gtk.EventBox):

    def __init__(self, label):

        Gtk.EventBox.__init__(self)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
        self.add(self.label)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def on_imagebutton_clicked(button, data=None):
        print("Button has been clicked!")

    window = Gtk.Window()
    button = ImageButton("My label")
    button.connect('button-press-event', on_imagebutton_clicked)
    window.add(button)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Instead of saying that my class it is a `Gtk.Widget`, I said that it is a `Gtk.EventBox` and I started it like it. From now on `ImageButton` will have the same attributes and methods like an `Gtk.EventBox`.

*If I've made the same example by using `Gtk.Button` instead of a `Gtk.EventBox` **you could call** `button.connect(..` instead of `buton.connect.connect(..` as you want it in your question. The problem with this is that if `ImageButton` it is a `Gtk.Button` It is not any more possible of modifying it to do things that buttons don't do ( like adding containers and labels).

**In a Few Words:**

You can create a custom widget based in other widget, but only one widget will be at the top of the tree.

```
--> Parent  
---------> Child
---------> Child
```

So when you do `self.method` it will always look to:

1) Your parent methods (the one you copied by using `Gtk.EventBox.__init__(self)`

2) The methods you created.

Alternatively you can lie thanks to this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ImageButton(Gtk.EventBox):

    def __init__(self, label):

        Gtk.EventBox.__init__(self)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
        self.add(self.label)    

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.label.set_text(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def on_imagebutton_clicked(button, data=None):
        print("Button has been clicked!")

    window = Gtk.Window()
    button = ImageButton("My label")
    button.connect('button-press-event', on_imagebutton_clicked)
    button.set_text('New text!!')
    window.add(button)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Note that I didn't had to call `button.label.set_text(..)` I hope it be clear enough!